# Evaluating the double sum $\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2r+1)^{n}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2l+1)^{n+2}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

I want to find the value of $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2r+1)^{n}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2l+1)^{n+2}}.$$ For this I know that we can use the cauchy product of two infinte series and then  we have the new series as $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}$$ where $c_{k}= \sum_{j=0}^ka_{j}b_{k-j}$.

And so the double series will convert into the series
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{(2j+1)^n}\frac{1}{(2(k-j)+1)^{n+2}} .$$

However this doesn't seem to be helpful. Any ideas/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the restrictions on $n$ ?

Comment: That is not really a double sum, it is just a product of two infinite series.

Comment: @Gary but we can use the cauchy product of two infinite series and then have a single series, right? I think, I made a mistake in the title of question. I want to evaluate the resulting series.

Comment: @Kashif I do not see your point. You want to evaluate the single series. Well its value is the product of the two series which is evaluated in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

For integer $n>1$ we have that

$$\zeta(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n} \implies \sum_{k\text{ odd}} \frac{1}{k^n} = \zeta(n) - \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m)^n} = (1-2^{-n})\zeta(n)$$

The double sum you have is a product of two sums of odd terms, which evaluates to

$$(1-2^{-n})(1-2^{-n-2})\zeta(n)\zeta(n+2)$$

Comment: Yes this is true, and in fact I obtained the series in the reverse way of what you have done here. However I wanted to know that is there any way we can evaluate the single series after cauchy product?